# XSL: How to select the first 2 nodes in a list that meet certain criteria

Tags: xslt

If I have XML something like the following (students are sorted by score).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<students>
    <student>
        <name>Joe</name>
        <year>Freshman</year>
        <score>10</score>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Sam</name>
        <year>Senior</year>
        <score>7</score>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Mary</name>
        <year>Freshman</year>
        <score>4</score>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Ann</name>
        <year>Junior</year>
        <score>2</score>
    </student>
</students>
```

How can I use XSL to select the first 2 students that are not freshmen to end up with something like the following?

*Clarification from original post* - This is a simplified example of a transformation I'm trying to do at our ESB before forwarding it on to a third party. It is the third party that requires the message have distinct tags like name1 and name2.

```
<students>
    <name1>Sam</name1>
    <name2>Ann</name2>
</students>
```

I currently have the following XSL, but it obviously doesn't filter out the freshmen:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="students/student[1]">
        <xsl:element name="name1">
            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="students/student[2]">
        <xsl:element name="name2">
            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="students/student[position() > 2]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something simple:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/students">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="student[year != 'Freshman']"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="student">
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= 2">
        <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note: using your example, this will return:

```
<students>
   <name>Sam</name>
   <name>Ann</name>
</students>
```

IMHO, you *really* don't want to have a distinct element name for each student.

---

**EDIT:**

> It is the third party that requires the message have something like
>   `<name1>` and `<name2>`. –

Well, IMHO they will be sorry to get what they ask for. Anyway, you could do it the way shown by Daniel Haley, or perhaps:

```
...
<xsl:template match="student">
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= 2">
        <xsl:element name="{concat('student', position())}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>    
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

in case you want to include more details about the two students - either now or in the future.

Comment: Thanks. This does help. However, I do need it to be <name1> and <name2>. Sorry I didn't mention that from the start. This is a simplified example of a transformation I'm trying to do at our ESB before forwarding it on to a third party. It is the third party that requires the message have something like <name1> and <name2>.

Comment: You could also simplify by changing your select on xsl:apply-templates to `student[year != 'Freshman']/name` and changing your match="student" template to `<xsl:template match="name[2 >= position()]"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:template>`.

Comment: @user3124095 I have (somewhat reluctantly) added a variant to my answer.

Comment: @DanielHaley I didn't do that, because I suspect it doesn't end with name only.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I was able to use them to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer by user3016153, but adds the number to the `name` element.

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="students">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="student[not(year='Freshman')]/name"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <xsl:element name="name{position()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<students>
   <name1>Sam</name1>
   <name2>Ann</name2>
</students>
```

Also, I used `not(year='Freshman')` instead of `year != 'Freshman'`. This will include students that do not have a `year` element at all. If you don't want those students included, use `!=` instead of `not()`.